# It is possible to send emails with past dates using in domino using c#?

Tags: c#, email, lotus-domino

When i try to send email with past dates using `PostedDate` the emails are sended with current date time and not with the date specified in the `PostedDate` field. It is possible to send the emails with past dates and is there any other ways are there? Since I want large data in the past to test backup functionality(it is really needed).

```
  static void CreateEmail(NotesDatabase userDatabase)
{
    if (!userDatabase.IsOpen)
    {
        userDatabase.Open();
    }
    NotesDocument LNDocument = userDatabase.CreateDocument();
    string[] recipients =
 {"contact1/test@test","contact2/test@test"};
    string emailSender = "sender@test.com";

    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("From", emailSender);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SMTPOriginator", emailSender);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Sender", emailSender);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("INetFrom", emailSender);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", emailSender);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", recipients); //To field
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", "Test Email"); //message subject
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Body", "Test Email Lotus Notes"); //set body text
    System.DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 23, 7, 0, 0);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("PostedDate", StartDate);
    LNDocument.SaveMessageOnSend = true; //save message after it's sent
    LNDocument.Send(false,recipients ); //send
}
```

Comment: why don't you just roll back the clock in the server

Comment: @jsotola In my case i d't want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: Don't send them. The "PostedDate" item is an item that is automatically set by the router. You are not able to fake this date easily ("Hey, but I sent you the mail yesterday, look at the PostedDate..." ).

BUT: Instead of sending the mails you could simply directly create them in the recipients mailbox and set all the items as if it in deed had been sent.

The only additional thing the router does, is to put the mail in the inbox of the recipient, so you need to do that as well:

If you really want to keep the "sent" document in the senders database as well, then so something like this:

Instead of

```
LNDocument.SaveMessageOnSend = true; //save message after it's sent
LNDocument.Send(false,recipients ); //send
```

Write

```
NotesDatabase recipientDatabase
NotesDocument recipientDocument

LNDocument.Save(true,true,true); //save
// get the database of recipient here, lookup in ($User)- view 
// in names.nsf on server and get MailPath, write a function for this...
recipientDatabase = ....
recipientDocument = LNDocument.CopyToDatabase(recipientDatabase)
recipientDocument.PutInFolder( "($Inbox)" )
```

Comment: You have to get the recipient's mail server, too, and you have to have Author or Editor access to the destination mail database, and you have to deal with failure cases that the router would (mostly) handle for you by queueing for later. So I'd say that the answer isnt really "simple", but it is correct ;-)

Comment: You are absolutely right: I also omitted some facts (e.g. There is a PostedDate in senders‘ mailbox, but PostedDate + DeliveredDate at the recipients side). But I wanted to make clear: faking PostedDate the way he tries is not possible... and: I wrote „the answer is simple“, not that the solution is... ;)

Comment: @TorstenLink Thank for the valuable reply. It is worked now, but only the thing is that in receiver inbox the mail is looks like sent email (Unopened Yellow envelop)  not as a Message. The email should be as Message in Inbox folder of the receiver and Unopened Yellow envelope at sender Sent folder  but now in both Inbox and Sent folder it is like Unopened Yellow envelope.

Comment: That is what „DeliveredDate“ does: you need to set that in the recipients’ mailbox

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks:

1. For readability in C#, change variable names such that they start with a lower case letter. It makes them distinguishable from Class names. Both for the reader and the markup format. (At least LNDocument and StartDate)
2. Use the debugger, set a breakpoint on the last line, and inspect the LNDocument variable. Is the date set correctly?
3. In the documentation, it seems that a specific NotesDateTime is used: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDATETIME_CLASS.html . Maybe this datetime is not compatible with the System.DateTime?

Comment: I have tried to set "PostedDate" using  NotesDateTime like this ,

NotesDateTime dateTime = _lotusNotesServerSession.CreateDateTime("12/29/2019 01:36:22 PM");
lnDocument.ReplaceItemValue("PostedDate", dateTime);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.LocalTime);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.GMTTime);
12/29/2019 01:36:22 PM AST
12/29/2019 05:36:22 PM GMT the output for the above lines. But still mails send in the current date time.

Comment: Yes, I agree particularly about LNDocument. That is actually a class name in the Lotus C++ API. Seeing it in C# code as a variable name is potentially confusing for anyone who has ever worked with that API!